# pip, importError: cannot import name md5

Tags: pip, md5

When trying to use pip, pip3, for example to install a package, I am suddenly getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

What is it about?

Comment: What package is it exactly? It seems you are trying to install a source distribution of a python2-only package.